# Nested List View React Native

Tags: react-native

I need a nested List View like Safari's adding bookmark list. React for of that: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/listview/nested-list/

My data is nested it is shown below (small part of that):

```
const data = [
  {
    title: 'Computer',
  },
  {
    title: 'Software',
    items: [
      {
        title: 'JS',
      },
      {
        title: 'React JS',
        items: [
          {
            title: 'Components',
          },
          {
            title: 'Hooks',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

[image: Nested list view ex.]

Which package do you suggest ?

Comment: Check section list https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist

Comment: It is not enough deeper and not navigating to see sub folder. I added a photo to explain what I want. @GuruparanGiritharan

Comment: you dont need a package for this, you can simply have two views and navigate using your navigation library

Comment: I didnt want to write too long data for the explanation. My data's nested level would be 4,5,6.. it depends. Because of that I mentioned about the apple's safari bookmark folder structure. Your answer is for small data. @GuruparanGiritharan

Comment: I agree with @GuruparanGiritharan, using several views is simpler and would allow you to go as deep as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sectionList or map property for your array

using map:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    {data.map((item, index) => (
        <View key={index} style={{borderBottomColor: 'black', borderBottomWidth: 2}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{item.title}</Text>
            {item.items && <>
            {item.items.map((item, index) => (
                <View key={index} style={{backgroundColor: '#7fc', borderBottomColor: 'blue', borderBottomWidth: 2}}>
                      <Text style={{fontSize: 20, marginLeft: 40, color: 'blue'}}>{item.title}</Text>
                     {item.items && <>
                     {item.items.map((item, index) => (
                       <View key={index}  style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow', borderBottomColor: 'red', borderBottomWidth: 2}}>
                           <Text style={{fontSize: 16, marginLeft: 80,}}>{item.title}</Text>
                       </View>
                    ))}
                   </>}
               </View>
            ))}
           </>}
        </View>
     ))}
</View>
```

this is how you can apply this code to your required view
you can make your parent view to button and show or hide it with button press
child component should be seperate component

[image]

I hope this will help you!